# Importing modules in Angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

As per understanding , Node js uses CommonJS module pattern , and in CommonJS
pattern we use require() to import a node module.

In Angular 2 application development we use @angular/core , @angular/common etc
node modules.

My question is:

Why do we use "import {} from '@angular/core'"[which is ES6 module syntax]
instead of commonJS require() syntax for accessing node modules
in angular2 code files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this, is that Angular2 is written in TypeScript.

TypeScript is a superset of ES2015, and wants to be as close to ES2015 suggested syntax as possible. That's why you use the ES2015 import {} from syntax.

However, TypeScript also comes with a built-in transpiler (tsc). Meaning you write TypeScript code, but target a specific EcmaScript version in your [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

- When targetting ES5 and looking into the transpiled code, you will
  clearly see that behind the scenes TypeScript will translate import {} from to require()in the transpiled files.
- When targetting ES6, of course in the transpiled code, your imports will be ES2015 imports. Be aware that when targetting ES6, you will need [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your ES6 modules to ES5 or use [System.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) to load your ES6 modules in the browser.

Cheers